# building open_gmapping from source on melodic/ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

The short version of my question is: How can I  get gmapping running on Ubuntu 18.

I have been trying for a few days to get gmapping (http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping) running on my system (Ubuntu 18/melodic). Since I have ubuntu 18 I cannot use apt-get since gmapping is only released for kinetic/lunar, and in separate issues I have not been able to build either kinetic or lunar from source as a way to avoid building gmapping from source).

Per the instruction on https://openslam-org.github.io/gmapping, I understand I need to first compile CARMEN (http://carmen.sourceforge.net/). I tried following the instructions on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/carmen#1004lts, but this references ubuntu 7 so I am not shocked it does not work. By googling each error that came up I was able to eventually get the `./configure` command to complete without issue, but `make` fails with some pointer error in c files. Judging by how old the instructions I was following are I was thinking that there must be a better way to do this. The only "recent" reference to this processes I could find was a question asked regarding ubuntu 10 https://askubuntu.com/questions/573176/compiling-carmen-nav-toolkit-on-ubuntu-10-04.

Does any one have any suggestions/ has anyone got gmapping working on Ubuntu 18?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300480/building-open_gmapping-from-source-on-melodic/ubuntu-18.04/) by [roboticslife](https://answers.ros.org/users/36974/roboticslife/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-08-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-14**:
Just a note:

> I have not been able to build either kinetic or lunar from source as a way to avoid building gmapping from source

building ROS from source will not allow you to install additional packages using `apt` afterwards. It's all or nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit: update (2019-07-09): it would appear that at least `openslam_gmapping` has been released into Melodic now by the "ROS Orphaned Package Maintainers" (see [here](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/compare_kinetic_melodic.html?q=gmapping)).

That still leaves `gmapping` itself (ie: the ROS package), so building from source may still be necessary, but it seems that will be done as well ([ros-perception/slam_gmapping#72](https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping/issues/72)).

---

Instead of using vanilla upstream, using the latest (Kinetic/Lunar released) patched sources from [ros-perception/openslam_gmapping](https://github.com/ros-perception/openslam_gmapping) (linked from [wiki/openslam_gmapping](http://wiki.ros.org/openslam_gmapping)) built cleanly for me in a `ros:melodic` Docker container.

Adding [ros-perception/slam_gmapping](https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping) (linked from [wiki/slam_gmapping](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping)) to that same workspace and building it resulted in a happy `catkin_make`.

```
$ docker run -it --rm ros:melodic
(docker) $ apt update
(docker) $ rosdep update
(docker) $ mkdir -p /ros_ws/src
(docker) $ cd /ros_ws
(docker) $ git clone https://github.com/ros-perception/openslam_gmapping src/openslam_gmapping
(docker) $ git clone https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping src/slam_gmapping
(docker) $ rosdep install --from-paths src/ -i
(docker) $ catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo
```

I've not tested whether it actually all runs, but the fact it still compiles is nice.

---

After this works, you might also want to take a look at some of the open pull requests against both `ros-perception/openslam_gmapping` ([here](https://github.com/ros-perception/openslam_gmapping/pulls)) and `ros-perception/slam_gmapping` ([here](https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping/pulls)). They seem to propose a few enhancements and fixes especially for more recent systems and OS.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-14**:
You are probably aware of this already, but please note the `Maintainer status: unmaintained` for `gmapping`. There are better systems out there now, so this will not receive any updates any more.

**Comment by [roboticslife](https://answers.ros.org/users/36974/roboticslife/) on 2018-08-14**:
Thanks for your help @gvdhoorn! I had seen the openslam_gmapping package, but I must have made another mistake that prevented it from compiling. With respect to your comment, I am also working with cartographer, but in order to compare results to a previous paper I unfortunately need gmapping too...